# Welcome card doesnot pop up on its own while integrating it with direct line channel

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework, azure-storage-emulator

I have created a bot locally using bot framework v4 c#. It has a welcome card that automatically pops up as soon I connect my local url with emulator, but recently I deployed my bot on azure and integrated it using direct line channel in my website. Now whenever I click, it opens the bot but the welcome card does not come on its own ,it appears when I write something from my chatbot. I just want the welcome card to appaer automatically as it appears in the emulator. Guys can you help me out please? Below is the code of direct line which I am integrating in my website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<!-- Paste line 7 to 27 after the title tag in _Layout.cshtml -->
<link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" 
/>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
<style>
    #mychat {
        margin: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 30px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 1000000;
    }

    .botIcon {
        float: left !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .userIcon {
        float: right !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>
</head>
< body>
<!-- Paste line from 31 to 33 before the </body> tag at the end of code -->
<div id="container">
    <img id="mychat" src=""/>
</div>
</body>
```

```
<!-- Paste line 38 to 88 after the </html> tag -->
<script>
(function () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var user = {
                id: "",
                name: ''
            };

    var bot = {
                id: '',
                name: 'SaathiBot'
            };

    const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({

                secret: '',

                webSocket: false 
            })        

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);

    div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='width: 400px; height: 0px; margin:10px; position: 
fixed; bottom: 0; left:0; z-index: 1000;><div  id='botTitleBar' style='height: 40px; width: 400px;
```

position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'>";

```
    BotChat.App({
                botConnection: botConnection, 
                user: user,
                bot: bot 
            }, document.getElementById("botDiv"));

    document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].setAttribute("id", "chatbotheader");
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
        if (e.target.matches('#chatbotheader')) {
            var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');

            botDiv.style.height = "0px";

            document.getElementById("mychat").style.display = "block";
        };
    });

    document.getElementById("mychat").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

        document.getElementById("botDiv").style.height = '500px';

        e.target.style.display = "none";
    })
    }());
 </script>
```

Also here is my welcome card code in  c#

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
public class WelcomeUser : SaathiDialogBot<MainDialog>
{

    protected readonly string[] _cards =
    {
        Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "WelcomeCard.json"),

    };

    public WelcomeUser(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, MainDialog dialog, ILogger<SaathiDialogBot<MainDialog>> logger)
        : base(conversationState, userState, dialog, logger)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        Random r = new Random();
        var cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(_cards[r.Next(_cards.Length)]);
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(cardAttachment), cancellationToken);
    }


    private static async Task SendWelcomeMessageAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var member in turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {

                if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
                {

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
                        $"Hi,Good Morning {member.Name}",
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

                }
                else if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 17)
                {

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
                        $"Hi,Good Afternoon {member.Name}",
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
                        $"Hi,Good Evening {member.Name}",
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);


                }
            }
        }

    }
    private static Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(string filePath)
    {
        var adaptiveCardJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCardJson),
        };
        return adaptiveCardAttachment;
    }
    }
}
```

Here the saathiDialog code which inherited in welcome card. These are the two files inside my bot folder

```
public class SaathiDialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
{
    protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
    protected readonly Dialog Dialog;
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;
    protected readonly BotState UserState;
    private DialogSet Dialogs { get; set; }

    public SaathiDialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<SaathiDialogBot<T>> logger)
    {
        ConversationState = conversationState;
        UserState = userState;
        Dialog = dialog;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var activity = turnContext.Activity;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
        {
            activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
        }
        if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "Yes")
        {

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Good bye. I will be here if you need me. ", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Say Hi to wake me up.", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }
        await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        }

 }
}
here is main Dialog code
```

> ```
> namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
> {
> public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
> {
>     private const string UserInfo = "value-userInfo";
>     protected readonly ILogger _logger;
>     protected readonly string[] _cards =
>      {
>         Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "ValidationCard.json"),
>     };
>     public MainDialog(ILogger<MainDialog> logger) : base(nameof(MainDialog))
>     {
>         _logger = logger;
>         AddDialog(new ProductIssue($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.fromMain"));
>         AddDialog(new ProductIssue($"{nameof(Confirm)}.fromConfirm"));
>         AddDialog(new ProductIssue($"{ nameof(Resolution)}.resolution"));
>         AddDialog(new Confirm());
>         AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.issue"));
>         AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.callDialog"));
>         AddDialog(new NumberPrompt<int>($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.num", valinatiotionAsync));
>         AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow", new WaterfallStep[]
> ```

```
            {
            MoblieNumberAsync,
            ChoiceCardStepAsync,
            ShowCardStepAsync,
            CallingDialogsAsync
          }));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow";

    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> MoblieNumberAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values[UserInfo] = new UserInput();
        var options = new PromptOptions()
        {

            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Kindly enter your 10 digit mobile number without any spaces, dashes and country code. We will be sending an OTP later to this number "),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Incorrect mobile number entered. Please only enter the 10 digits of your mobile without any spaces, dashes and country code.")

        };

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.num", options, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceCardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        BotAPIBLL botApiBLL = new BotAPIBLL();

        var response =   botApiBLL.GetCustomerDetail(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text);

        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Fetching your details from our systems. This may take a moment"), cancellationToken);
        var options = new PromptOptions()
        {

            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Welcome user, How can we serve you ? "),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("That was not a valid choice, please select a option between 1 to 4."),
            Choices = GetChoices(),
        };

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.issue", options, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ShowCardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var reply = MessageFactory.Text("");
        var user_choice = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value;
        switch (user_choice)
        {
            case "Product issue":
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment3());
                break;

            case "Register Product":

                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard1().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Online Purchase":

                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard2().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Customer Grivance":

                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard3().ToAttachment());
                break;

            default:
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment3());
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard1().ToAttachment());
                break;
        }
        if (user_choice == "Register Product" || user_choice == "Online Purchase" || user_choice == "Customer Grivance")
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            Random r = new Random();
            var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_cards[r.Next(_cards.Length)]);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            var options2 = new PromptOptions() { Prompt = reply, RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Retry") };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.callDialog", options2, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CallingDialogsAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();
        if (choice.ToLower() == "no")
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.fromMain", null, cancellationToken);

        }
        else
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(Confirm), null, cancellationToken);
    }

    private IList<Choice> GetChoices()
    {
        var cardOptions = new List<Choice>()
            {

                new Choice() { Value = "Product issue", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "adaptive" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Register Product", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Online Purchase", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Customer Grivance", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } },
            };

        return cardOptions;
    }

    private Task<bool> valinatiotionAsync(PromptValidatorContext<int> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string value = (string)promptContext.Context.Activity.Text;
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9]{10}$"))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }




}
}
```

Comment: Please Post your C# code of how are you initiating the welcome card

Comment: Hi, i just posted my welcome card code of c#..Is their anything else you want

Comment: plez help me out..

Comment: you didn't post your MainDialog

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **ConversationUpdate** event **ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate**

This is an example inside of a Switch statement where i check the different ActivityTypes i get, and the conversationUpdate is used to show the welcome message

```cs
       case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
                        {
                            if (activity.MembersAdded?.Count > 0)
                            {
                              await innerDc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(dialog));  
                            }

                            break;
                        }
```

**UPDATE**

Look at this working example and explanation on how to send a [Welcome Message Event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) from WebChat.

Comment: can you tell where and what code i should add i welcome card to fix this issue. i new to bot and getting confused now. help out @Marc

Comment: You have to check this event in the Main Dialog and from there you begin the welcome dialog

Comment: I just posted my saathidialog code which inherited in  welcome card. After this page we go to dialog

Comment: plez help me marc .. i am very new to bot

Comment: Do you have a dialog called MainDialog.cs ?

Comment: yes i do have that..i posting that code even..plez -Marc Asmar help me out

Comment: I just posted the code of main dialog..plez help out

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using WebChat or directline, the bot’s ConversationUpdate is sent when the conversation is created and the user sides’ ConversationUpdate is sent when they first send a message. When ConversationUpdate is initially sent, there isn’t enough information in the message to construct the dialog stack. The reason that this appears to work in the emulator, is that the emulator simulates a sort of pseudo DirectLine, but both conversationUpdates are resolved at the same time in the emulator, and this is not the case for how the actual service performs.

A workaround would be to send a back channel welcome event to the bot when the DirectLine connection is established and send a welcome message from the onEventAsync handler instead of onMembersAdded.

- Embedded HTML for Web Chat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div style="position: relative; height: 500px; width: 500px"><div id="bot" ></div></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      (async function() {
        const res = await fetch('/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token }  = await res.json();
        var userinfo = {
              id: 'user-id',
              name: 'user name',
              locale: 'es'
          };

        var botConnection = new window.BotChat.DirectLine({ token });

        botConnection.connectionStatus$
          .subscribe(connectionStatus => {
              switch(connectionStatus) {
                  case window.BotChat.ConnectionStatus.Online:
                    botConnection.postActivity({
                        from: { id: 'myUserId', name: 'myUserName' },
                        type: 'event',
                        name: 'webchat/join',
                        value: { locale: 'en-US' }
                    }).subscribe(
                        id => console.log("Posted welcome event, assigned ID ", id),
                        error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
                    );
                    break;
              }
          });


        BotChat.App({
          botConnection: botConnection,
          user: userinfo,
          bot: { id: 'botid' },
          resize: 'detect'
        }, document.getElementById("bot"));

      })().catch(err => console.log(err));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Bot Code in C#

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join") {
      await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Welcome Message!");
    }
}

protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "webchat" && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "directline") {

        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Hi there - {member.Name}. {WelcomeMessage}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(InfoMessage, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(PatternMessage, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this a solution for v3..can plez look into my help with the changes,